# Should Salesforce developers do more pair programming?

Tags: developer

Pair programming in the software industry seems to have varying acceptance (a different subject). I don't have a strong opinion on it and I don’t have much experience neither. But recently I had a few of productive pair programming sessions in a week writing some Apex code using VS Code. The other colleague and I can certainly feel the benefits and would like to do more (COVID-19 seems to impact the pair programming, but could turn out to be the other way around for some by improving the social connection). This question is really about the adoption of pair programming in the Salesforce platform, considering some of the platform specific challenges like:

- Bulkification, although almost embedded into every Salesforce developer's blood, is sometimes still dismissed or mistakenly used, even by an experienced developer.
- More declarative approaches (process builder, formulas, flow, etc.) to simplify some of the coding tasks.
- Platform specific security issues.
- ISV managed packages security review issues.
- Naming things: it is harder as there is no 'package' concept to separate classes so classes with the same name is not possible (2nd generation might help in the future).
- Various limits and considerations - not just governor limits, but also restrictions and considerations (like the choose between Master-detail and Lookup, the choose between the before and the after triggers, execution order, etc.).

The list can go on. Not being in the intention to list all the unique features and restrictions of the platform, I realise that it is a huge platform itself with no one being able to get all the aspects of it (arguably this happens everywhere).

Conversely, should Salesforce developers do less pair programming? One could argue that in the Salesforce environment less code needs to be written, and some principles are enforced more strictly than you may be used to. You don't get that many options on using a third party library. Therefore, Salesforce developers need less pair programming, at least no compelling reason to do more.

But that argument is not compatible with my reality. The point here is that in the context of programming (coding is unavoidable), should we do more pair programming? Is it even worth thinking about it compared to other languages?

Comment: my 2 cents - we enforce architectural standards in our org - namely fflib Enterprise pattern which removes a lot of "individuality" and use pull requests with approver reviews

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. That certainly helps removing errors. We also have some standards in place. The pairing seems to remove all kinds of errors much faster and enforce those standards even more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

While this is probably subjective/opinion-based, I would agree that pair programming is a practice that should be encouraged in most cases. When developers of varying degrees work together on a project, their different levels of expertise tend to result in code that's not homogeneous, and can be more challenging to maintain long term. It's also possible that one developer's code can inadvertently affect another developer's code.

Pair programming isn't even about catching more bugs quickly; it's about improving individual developers' skills, which in turn improves the code quality of the system as a whole. With pair programming, everyone benefits. Along with pair programming, static analysis and code reviews should be employed so that not just glaring errors, but also minor performance problems, are more likely to be spotted before getting to production.

I haven't performed any studies on the topic, nor am I technically an expert on all things Salesforce (though, arguably, I do know quite a bit). I am simply reflecting on the past 13 years of Salesforce development that I have experienced in variously-sized teams, from me going solo to working on a team with a few dozen developers working lockstep with developers for other systems on a standard agile release cycle.

In many systems, you can get away with code that's "good enough", as the product will eventually be "finished" in some sense (yes, you may have bug fixes/maintenance, but you're basically *done*). With Salesforce, the system inevitably grows more complex, and old features need to be pruned as new features are added. Until recently, we haven't had modern tools to help us do that, and even migrating to those now-available new tools are a challenge.

It's true that you need code less as new declarative features are added. However, code is not going away, either. Someone somewhere will always need code to do something that declarative work can't do. Developers tend to be more a blend of DBA/Admin/Developer than most other computer systems, so they may not always be writing code, but every action they take will have an affect on the system as a whole; I would state that "pair administration" should also be a thing. Fewer mistakes happen when a second person is involved as a sanity check.

Comment: Great points. Truely everyone benefits, so as the whole development team. The fast evolving platform makes the pairing more valuable. And that "pair administration" seems to be the unique thing here on Salesforce.